# Undefined offset 1: when passing a file using ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I pass data into my file upload controller, it is giving an error of `undefined offset: 1`.

```
function TestFileUpload() {
    $i=0;
    if(!isset($_FILES[$i]) ) {
        echo "No file is being uploaded";
    }
    else {
    $x = $_FILES[$i]['name'];
    $xx = explode('.', $x);


    $config['upload_path'] = 'MRS-files\Upload_files';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|doc|jpg|png|gif|pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    $count = count($_FILES[$i]['name']). '  ';

        while ($i <= 4 ) 
        {
            echo $count;
            $x = $_FILES[$i]['name'];
            $xx=explode(".", $x);
            echo $_FILES[$i]['name'].' '.$_FILES[$i]['type'].' '.$_FILES[$i]['size'] ;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $_FILES['up']['name']       = $_FILES[$i]['name'];
            $_FILES['up']['tmp_name']   = $_FILES[$i]['tmp_name'];
            $_FILES['up']['type']       = $_FILES[$i]['type'];
            $_FILES['up']['size']       = $_FILES[$i]['size'];

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('up')) {
                //error on uploading
                echo str_replace('','',$this->upload->display_errors()); //temporary commented no use cause of redirect to homepage
                //$this->cancelREC();
                exit();
            }

            else{
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->new_development_model->insertonAttachments($data['upload_data']);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ajax file upload` i cant find AJAX Code here

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related cause you need to check in your loop if `$_FILES[$i]` is defined.

You do this but only one time, when `$i = 0`.

I even think that if you check in the loop, you wont need to do

```
if(!isset($_FILES[$i]) ) {
    echo "No file is being uploaded";
}
else { /*...*/ }
```

before the loop